# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 - Can we stop service log getting replicated in to wso2carbon.log

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can we stop service logs getting replicated in to "wso2carbon.log" in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3?

We have set up per service logs and we do not want the per service log getting replicated in the "wso2carbon.log"

I would be really thankful if any body can let me know.

Here is my typical log4j configuration

```
log4j.category.SERVICE_LOGGER.TQS_RMA=INFO, TQS_RMA_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.SERVICE_LOGGER.TQS_RMA=false
log4j.appender.TQS_RMA_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TQS_RMA_APPENDER.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/tqs-rma-service.log
log4j.appender.TQS_RMA_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.TQS_RMA_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.TQS_RMA_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tried, setting [additivity false](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Appenders_and_Layouts) should prevent logs being directed to ancestors.

See docs for [service logging with WSO2 ESB](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/Per-Service+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB).

See also this [blog post](http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2012/03/logging-with-wso2-esb.html) for information.